# View.setBackground throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, view, nosuchmethoderror

The following code:

```
View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable((Integer) (item.get("img")));
inflate.findViewById(R.id.page_img).setBackground(img);
```

produces the following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setBackground`

I have no idea why. I already tried the setBackground with `R.drawable.img` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This method was introduced in API level 16, you are most probably running on an earlier one:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Use setBackgroundDrawable()

Answer (score 2):

`setBackground` method was added in API 16 so if you are testing it on lower than that it will give `NoSuchMethodError`

[Check this link for api level details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Answer (score 1):

yeah, please read the api:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

and you should know setBackground works when level 16, so you should always think about one thing, that is should i use a level 1 method instead......

hope this is helpful to you.